# High Pass Filter in java code

Tags: java, android, matlab, accelerometer

I'm trying to implement a high pass filter to my accelerometer data to omit the in influence of the gravity.

Android offers a method of having a 1st order IIR low pass filter to grab the gravity values from the accelerometer data and then subtract those gravity values from the original values (high pass filter) to obtain a filtered signal without the influence of the gravity (this is the linear acceleration).

However, this method is not convenient to what I'm doing, the response of this 1st order filter is very weak because it changes the amplitude in a severe way.

I need to directly implement a high pass filter to my accelerometer data, the cutoff frequency is 10Hz and the sample rate is 100Hz (sample rate of accelerometer reading in note II). I can have the filter designed in Matlab to get the coefficients, But I need the java (or C and I do the translation) code for the filter itself.

Any help please?

Comment: Did you get any solution for your issue? Please share.

Comment: We were trying with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291582/implementing-a-high-pass-filter-to-an-audio-signal

Comment: I am trying to do same thing. Did you guys find anything?