# How do I identify CUTOFF frequency from my audio signal?

Tags: frequency, highpass-filter

I was able to recorded an audio signal through the MIC and i applied FFT and Hanning window function to it. Now I want to know how do I identify CUTOFF frequency from it to apply the High Pass Filter.

my sample rate = 8000 Hz, FFT block size = 256

Can anyone help me to identify this ? I would really appreciate it ! :)

Thanks!

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with your high pass filter ?

Comment: @ paul thanks for the reply. Actually I need to cut-down some higher frequencies which is unnecessarily performed. I am trying to do a music identification system. Therefore after apply the FFT I should apply High Pass Filter to my code according to my main research paper which I was used ( " Robust Audio Fingerprint Extraction Algorithm Based on 2-D Chroma " ). When I was tried to apply this function it requires a CUTOFF frequency and sample rate. Sorry if there is any grammar error. Because English is not my language.

Comment: OK - well only you and perhaps the author of the paper know what frequencies you want to remove. Since this is not really a programming question you might want to try asking on http://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I was founded some API to do that function. But I was not able to apply that code according to my code. I have already post that question  and my code snippets  here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291582/implementing-a-high-pass-filter-to-an-audio-signal)